# How to catch "$variable is not defined" in jq?

Tags: jq

Let's pretend I'm running something like this:

```sh
jq -nr --arg target /tmp \
  '(["echo","Hello, world"]|@sh)+">\($target)/sample.txt"' \
| sh
```

Everything is fine unless I forgot to pass variable `$target`:

```sh
$ jq -nr '(["echo","Hello, world"]|@sh)+">\($target)/sample.txt"'
jq: error: $target is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
(["echo","Hello, world"]|@sh)+">\($target)/sample.txt"
jq: 1 compile error
```

How can I catch this and use default value?

I've tried:

1. `$target?`
2. `($target)?`
3. `try $target catch null`
4. `$target? // null`

But it seems to be parsing-time error, which obviously can't be caught at runtime. Have I've missed any dynamic syntax?

I've found that command-line arguments can be found in `$ARGS.name`, but there are two drawbacks:

1. This was introduced in version 1.6, but I have 1.5 on CentOS 7.
2. It doesn't catch locally defined variables.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible without $ARGS.name, since referencing an undefined variable is a *compile* error; i.e it halts the program before executing any code

Comment: Indeed, $ARGS was introduced to resolve (or at least provide a workaround) for the problem you've identified.  `jq -n '$x'`should, however, return a non-zero error code (but it varies from one version to another).

Comment: At least this will hint others that only solution is to upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you need to do something more useful with jq than write 'Hello World' over a text file. I propose the following,
Maybe we can learn some programming tips from Jesus:

"Give to Caesar what belongs to Caesar, and give to God what belongs to God"

Suppose that Caesar is bash shell and God is jq, bash is appropriate to work and test the existence of files, directories and environment variables, jq is appropriate to process information in json format.

```
#!/bin/bash
dest_folder=$1

#if param1 is not given, then the default is /tmp:
if [ -z $dest_folder ]; then dest_folder=/tmp ; fi
echo destination folder:  $dest_folder

#check if destination folder exists
if [ ! -d $dest_folder ]
  then
    echo "_err_ folder not found"
    exit 1
fi

jq -nr --arg target $dest_folder  '(["echo","Hello, world"]|@sh)+">\($target)/sample.txt"' | sh

#if the file is succesfully created, return 0, if not return 1
if [ -e "$dest_folder/sample.txt" ]
  then
    echo "_suc_ file was created ok"
    exit 0
  else
    echo "_err_ when creating file"
    exit 1
fi
```

Now you can include this script as a step in a more complex batch, because it is congruent with linux style, returning 0 on success.